# How to select first or last child in jss

Tags: jss

I'm using `JSS(Javascript Style Sheets)` in my React project. I was trying to select `first-child` or `last-child`, so I tried the following

```
carousel: {
  "& img:first-child": {
    padding: "0 5px"
  }
},
```

However, it doesn't work. In Chrome Developer tool, it correctly shows right CSS codes, however for some reaons, it selects every img tags, not just first-child. How can I select only first element in JSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSS is just a compiler, once it produced valid CSS and you verified its correctness, you have to search somewhere else for a mistake. Your selector looks OK to me.

Comment: Gotta double check one more time. Thank you for making sure the selector!

Answer (score 1):

However **if you just care about the first child inside a container** not the type of child then you can just use

```
carousel: {
  "& > :first-child": {
    padding: "0 5px"
  }
},
```

- Generally all the child inside of a container belongs to the same type, so type of child doesn't matter everytime.